# jq: Why do two expressions which produce identical output produce different output when surrounded by an array operator?

Tags: jq

I have been trying to understand `jq`, and the following piuzzle is giving me a headache: I can construct two expressions, `A` and `B`, which seem to produce the same output. And yet, when I surround them with `[]` array construction braces (as in `[A]` and `[B]`), they produce different output. In this case, the expressions are:

```
A := jq  '. | add'
B := jq -s `.[] | add`
```

Concretely:

```
$ echo '[1,2] [3,4]' | jq  '.'
[1,2]
[3,4]
$ echo '[1,2] [3,4]' | jq  '. | add'
3
7
# Now surround with array construction and we get two values:
$ echo '[1,2] [3,4]' | jq '[. | add]'
[3]
[7]

$ echo '[1,2] [3,4]' | jq -s '.[]'
[1,2]
[3,4]
$ echo '[1,2] [3,4]' | jq -s '.[] | add'
3
7
# Now surround with array construction and we get only one value:
$ echo '[1,2] [3,4]' | jq -s '[.[] | add]'
[3,7]
```

What is going on here? Why is it that the `B` expression, which applies the `--slurp` setting but appears to produce identical intermediate output to the `A` expression, produces different output when surrounded with `[]` array construction brackets?

Answer (score 1):

When `jq` is fed with a stream, just like `[1,2] [3,4]` with two inputs, it executes the filter independently for each. That's why `jq '[. | add]'` will produce two results; each addition will separately be wrapped into an array.

When `jq` is given the `--slurp` option, it combines the stream to an array, rendering it just one input. Therefore `jq -s '[.[] | add]'` will have one result only; the multiple additions will be caught by the array constructor, which is executed just once.